# The app does not open on sauce labs cloud

Tags: android, node.js, iphone, webdriver-io, saucelabs

context:
After I launched test suite on android and iPhone devices the session is closed because of time out. Apparently the app it’s not being even opened inside Sauce Labs cloud.

parameters:
I command used "ionic cordova build android --prod"
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
Node              : v9.6.1
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
```

testing:

./node_modules/.bin/wdio -v4.12.0
 appium v1.8.0

Issue: 
The delay between open the app and the homepage is longer, it takes 2 min.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing this kind of issues on sauce lab when we are executing test scripts on app(android/iOS). It will take longer time to load app and open in sauce vm. This is issue from sauce lab side. For assistance you can contact sauce lab support team.For browser it will not take longer time.
Note: I can not add comment on your answer due to that reason I have mentioned as answer